# Call out value into input field in PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

How to display SQL result into text input?
When I press the generate button it should appear in the input text.

```
<?php
        $random_name = "";
        $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","wordlist");
        if(!$conn)
        {
            die("Connection Error!");
        }
        $query_random = "SELECT kata FROM list ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query_random);
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
        {
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
            {
                $random_name = $row["kata"];
            }
        }
        mysqli_close($conn);
    ?>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container" >
<form action="#">
    <h4>Word Generator : </h4>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control">
        </div><br>
            <button id="generate-btn" type="submit" title="Generate Word">Generate</button>
        </div>
</form>
```

Comment: you just need to add this in your code <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo @$random_name ?>">

Comment: @ShakeelAhmad Please make an official answer so that the question then can be resolved

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add this in place of your input, your code is correct but you missed to print the value, that's all

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo @$random_name ?>">
```